# How can I get Minecraft to only use my CPU and not my GPU?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a MS Surface Pro 6, not really meant for gaming but since (prior to the ray-tracing update) Minecraft only really used my CPU I've been able to lightly game. The GPU would not be used at all, only the CPU which is powerful enough that it ran smoothly even with shaders.

Now, however, the game uses more of my GPU (Integrated Graphics) so the performance has significantly dropped. The GPU is constantly being taxed more than it can handle while the CPU does not much at all anymore. I want to tell MC to use the CPU like it did before so my performance can go back to normal. I can't do ray tracing (no Nvidia card) so the GPU's function in game is useless to me and is only hindering my capability. Does anyone know how to do this? Or if nothing else, how to uninstall the recent update? SP6, MC Bedrock Windows 10 Edition, i5 - Integrated Graphics.

Comment: As for your last point - I would not recommend not updating the game as a solution (that is just my recommendation though, of course you do what you wish)

Comment: Okay, I'll not do that then. At least not for now.